# image processing the Chain

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, chain

I've this code below, and I was asked to modify it, to add x[] and y[], and save the coordinates of boundary into x[] and y[]

the code does read an image as matrix, 2X2, and if any object found, it calculate the perimeters. boundaries of the object found.

ps. Chain code, is basically Freeman Chain Code

I'll add a pic of how it works, 
[image]

can someone help me please, I would be very thankful,

```
// compute the chain code of the object begninning at pixel (i,j)
//and return the direction code as NN integers in the array C[] , and coordinates of boundary in x[] and y[]

    void chain8 (struct image *x, int *c, int i, int j, int *nn)
    {
        int val,n,m,q,r, di[9],dj[9],ii,dii;
        int lastdir, jj;

    /*      Table given index offset for each of the 8 directions.          */
        di[0] = 0;      di[1] = -1;     di[2] = -1;     di[3] = -1;
        dj[0] = 1;      dj[1] = 1;      dj[2] = 0;      dj[3] = -1;
        di[4] = 0;      di[5] = 1;      di[6] = 1;      di[7] = 1;
        dj[4] = -1;     dj[5] = -1;     dj[6] = 0;      dj[7] = 1;

        for (ii=0; ii<200; ii++) c[ii] = -1;    /* Clear the code table */
        val = x->data[i][j];    n = 0;  /* Initialize for starting pixel */
        q = i;  r = j;  lastdir = 4;

        do {
           m = 0;
           dii = -1; 
           for (ii=lastdir+1; ii<lastdir+8; ii++) {     /* Look for next */
              jj = ii%8;
              if (range(x,di[jj]+q, dj[jj]+r))
            if ( x->data[di[jj]+q][dj[jj]+r] == val) {
               dii = jj;    m = 1;
               break;
            } 
           }

           if (m) {     /* Found a next pixel ... */
            if (n<200) c[n++] = dii;        /* Save direction as code */
            q += di[dii];   r += dj[dii];
            lastdir = (dii+5)%8;
           } else break;        /* NO next pixel */
           if (n>200) break;
        } while ( (q!=i) || (r!=j) );   /* Stop when next to start pixel */

        *nn = n;
    }
```

Comment: The boundaries of what? And what does this code do? Clarify the question, please

Comment: sure, sorry for not being clear

Comment: the code does read an image as matrix, 2X2, and if any object found, it calculate the perimeters. boundaries of the object found.

Comment: Repeating what you wrote in your question doesn't clarify anything. Please show the image you are working with and explain your question more clearly else it will get closed.

Comment: I add some explanation I hope it's more clear, the image is just 2X2 1s and 0s ,

Comment: "Chain code, is basically Freeman Chain Code" No, the chain code you show here **is** the Freeman chain code.

Comment: Note that adding the picture (I hope you're not infringing on copyright laws by posting it here, please state the source!) doesn't make this question any better. You dump code that is not yours (and you don't understand, I guess) and ask us to do your work for you. That is not a suitable question for SO.

Comment: Your image is 2x2 - so it has 4 pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `q` and `r` contain current pixel coordinates. You start with pixel `q = i, r = j`. In the external loop you do:

1. Find the boundary dirrection index `dii`. You sequentially (counterclockwise) look through all directions starting from the last direction `lastdir` and find pixel with color `val`. You use `dii` as direction index, from wich you can get pixel offsets using lookup tables `di` and  `dj`.
2. Updade current pixel position by adding pixel offsets (dx, dy) coresponded to direction `dii` to current coordinates `q += di[dii];   r += dj[dii];`

You need to store `q` and `r` for bounary pixels to arrays `bx` and `by`. It's easy enough:

```
bx[n] = q;
by[n] = r;
```

So you final code will be

```
// compute the chain code of the object begninning at pixel (i,j)
//and return the direction code as NN integers in the array C[] , and coordinates of boundary in bx[] and by[]

void chain8(struct image *x, int* bx, int* by,  int *c, int i, int j, int *nn)
{
   int val, n, m, q, r, di[9], dj[9], ii, dii;
   int lastdir, jj;

   /*      Table given index offset for each of the 8 directions.          */
   di[0] = 0;      di[1] = -1;     di[2] = -1;     di[3] = -1;
   dj[0] = 1;      dj[1] = 1;      dj[2] = 0;      dj[3] = -1;
   di[4] = 0;      di[5] = 1;      di[6] = 1;      di[7] = 1;
   dj[4] = -1;     dj[5] = -1;     dj[6] = 0;      dj[7] = 1;

   for (ii = 0; ii<200; ii++) by[ii] = bx[ii] = c[ii] = -1;    /* Clear the code table */
   val = x->data[i][j];    n = 0;  /* Initialize for starting pixel */
   q = i;  r = j;  lastdir = 4;

   do {
      m = 0;
      dii = -1;
      for (ii = lastdir + 1; ii<lastdir + 8; ii++) {     /* Look for next */
         jj = ii % 8;
         if (range(x, di[jj] + q, dj[jj] + r))
            if (x->data[di[jj] + q][dj[jj] + r] == val) {
               dii = jj;    m = 1;
               break;
            }
      }

      if (m) {     /* Found a next pixel ... */
         q += di[dii];   r += dj[dii];
         if (n < 200)
         {
            c[n] = dii;        /* Save direction as code */
            bx[n] = q;
            by[n] = r;
            n++;
         }

         lastdir = (dii + 5) % 8;
      }
      else break;        /* NO next pixel */
      if (n>200) break;
   } while ((q != i) || (r != j));   /* Stop when next to start pixel */

   *nn = n;
}
```

Comment: your explanation was very Very helpful, thank you so much, I now I understand it much better.